# DRY for field formula in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We have some SQL in Oracle which looks like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN
      field1 - field2 + field3 < 0
    THEN
      0
    ELSE
      field1 - field2 + field3
  END
```

we'd like to specify `field1 - field2 + field3` once, whilst not altering the output of the SELECT query. Is there any neat way to do this?

As an alternative, if there is a function which can return a numeric value above 0 and returns 0 for negative values that would work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `greatest()`:

```
select greatest(field1 - field2 + field3, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.  If you wrap it in a stored procedure you can return the result.

```
DECLARE
    n number := field1 - field2 + field3;
BEGIN
   CASE
       WHEN
           n < 0
       THEN
           0
       ELSE
           n
   END CASE
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN
      expr < 0
    THEN
      0
    ELSE
      expr
  END
FROM (SELECT field1 - field2 + field3 as expr
      FROM ... );
```